# CSS website fit to width of device

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

So, I am working on a web project, when I encountered a problem when viewing the website on, pretty much, any mobile device. The problem was that, when you first enter the page, the full width of the page would not be displayed, only a small portion of it. I am looking for a solution to correct this problem, without changing all of my code, or implementing a framework, such as bootstrap.

The domain is [the-salon.uk](http://www.the-salon.uk) if you would like to see the problem for yourself.

Thanks, all.

Harrison

[How it appears on Desktop - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFhfg.png)

[How it appears on mobiles - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDLyu.png)

Comment: you should research "responsive design". It doesn't require any framework but it can help give you a kickstart if you employ one. Whatever you decide to do, in order to get a decent result it will probably involve a reasonable amount of change to your CSS and some of your HTML, to be perfectly honest. You could just naively do something like set the width to 100% and leave it at that, but the likelihood is it'll just make the site un-readable on mobile because the text will be too small.

Comment: `width:100%` or `width:100vw` (ViewportWidth%)

Comment: You might find this article helpful: [Responsive Web Design Basics @ Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/)  :D

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

after the `<html>` tag. This will make sure your website covers the device's viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You could fudge it by explicitly specifying the width in the meta viewport tag... eg:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000px, initial-scale=1.0">
```

To be perfectly clear, that won't make for a great user experience. It's quite bad in fact, but it will keep all of the content on the page. Users will have to pinch-zoom to use anything though.

Like the comments say, you should look into responsive design. It's really too broad a topic for a SO answer, but it involves using a combination of percentage based/flexible items and css `media-queries` (look it up) to change the layout of the page at certain screen widths.

Hope that helps somewhat! I'd slap in the change to the meta-viewport as a hot-fix since your site is already live, and then go about the process of learning how to make it responsive. I definitely don't advocate using that viewport trick long term.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything to fit on the screen, I highly suggest using percentages rather than pixels. Instead of width: 400px, I suggest:

```
width: 100%
```

This ensures that the block takes up a certain percentage regardless of which device you are running on.

I can't see your source code, so I can't give any specific feedback. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you have width set to an absolute value, I would change this if you have it in the css:

```
width:{Amount}px
```

To something more like this

```
width:{Amount}%
```

This type of declaration is a relative value meaning it changes with either the size of the browser or the position/size of other elements. If it doesn't resize, odds are you have it set to an absolute value (using the px keyword).[This might be useful for you](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)

EDIT

Oop apparently someone said the exact thing as I was typing this up RIP, GG Knightsoul

Answer (score 0):

Add this code will fix your problem.

```
   @media (max-width: 520px) {
     .menu { width: 100%;}
     .menu li {
        float: none
        height: 32px;
        width: auto;
        padding: 0px 6px;
    }
    #greeting {
        padding-right: 25px;
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    #banner {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        max-width: 800px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        background-image: url(/Images/home_background.jpeg);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" />
```

Try this.

Hope this helps.